# Android Admob Failed to load ad: 0 - Error waiting for future TimeoutException Problem with OREO only

Tags: android, ads, admob, timeoutexception

I am facing some issues with Admob, I don't know why but it's problem with OREO only. I am getting following errors If I run application in OREO only, in other versions working perfectly.

I searched a lot on Google, SO but didn't find any solution.

```
10-19 14:02:47.991 3124-12984/? E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.af.get(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):18)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):62)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):169)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.m.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
10-19 14:02:47.992 26870-26887/com.xxx.xxx W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
10-19 14:02:47.993 26870-26870/com.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Any help?

Comment: post your code,,,

Comment: I have done same to same as per docs, it is also displaying ads in lower version then OREO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers from my application only.

**You just have to wait for 2-3 days minimum.**

Today I checked after 3 days and its working properly without any changes in my code.